# Can a scrollController.animateTo be cancelled or interrupted in the middle of its scroll?

Tags: flutter, dart

Can a scrollController.animateTo be cancelled or interrupted in the middle of its scroll?

For example, lets say I have a  `listview`  and I want to  `animateTo`  the bottom over the course of 10 seconds:

```
_scrollController.animateTo
(
   _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
    duration: Duration(seconds: 10),
    curve: Curves.linear
);
```

But 5 seconds into this, some event occurs, say a state change, so I want to immediately cancel the scroll wherever it happens to be.  Is this possible?

Comment: `_scrollController.position.hold(() { })` - the docs for `hold()` method say: *"Stop the current activity and start a HoldScrollActivity."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a better solution but this seems to work.

You can call `animateTo` again, except with the current position as the destination, and 0 seconds as the duration.

You can try with this demo below:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: ScrollDemoWidget(),
    ),
  );
}

class ScrollDemoWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const ScrollDemoWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ScrollDemoWidgetState createState() => _ScrollDemoWidgetState();
}

class _ScrollDemoWidgetState extends State<ScrollDemoWidget> {
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Scroll Demo'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_upward),
            onPressed: () {
              double current = _scrollController.position.pixels;
              double extent = _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent;
              double millis = 10 * 1000 * (current / extent);

              _scrollController.animateTo(0,
                  duration: Duration(milliseconds: millis.round()),
                  curve: Curves.linear);
            },
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
            onPressed: () {
              double current = _scrollController.position.pixels;
              double extent = _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent;
              double millis = 10 * 1000 * (1 - (current / extent));

              _scrollController.animateTo(
                  _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
                  duration: Duration(milliseconds: millis.round()),
                  curve: Curves.linear);
            },
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.stop),
            onPressed: () {
              _scrollController.animateTo(_scrollController.position.pixels,
                  duration: const Duration(seconds: 0), curve: Curves.linear);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        controller: _scrollController,
        itemCount: 100,
        itemBuilder: (context, i) => ListTile(title: Text('Tile $i')),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```